# PostgreSQL 10 logical Replication not working !!! slots blocking calls not sending wal events back to client

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.6

Postgres logical replication not working

we have created logical replication slot on pg 10 using below command

```
select * 
from pg_create_logical_replication_slot('slot', 'wal2json');
```

Above request creates slot on database

```
 select * from pg_replication_slots;
```

[image]

PG replication not returning stream events using slot listen command.

Slots size automatically increases to high value.

Below are postgress level global configs

```
archive_mode=off
archive_command=(disabled)
ssl=off
wal_level=logical
shared_preload_libraries=decoderbufs, wal2json
wal_keep_segments=100
max_replication_slots=100
max_wal_senders=30
wal_sender_timeout=0
max_standby_streaming_delay=-1
```

Question:

1. What is best configuration for pg logical replication to fix our issue?
2. Which is best plugin for logical replication our of below options:

   - wal2json
   - test decoding
   - protobuf

Please provide inputs to fix our issue.

Comment: Did you add tables to the subscriber?

Comment: We are using JDBC replication connection to listen wal .how to add table subscribers ?

Comment: How can you tell that replication is not working as expected? Does `wal2json` not receive the subscribed changes?

Comment: yes , I have try even using test_decode plugin in that also I am not getting events from table for changes

Comment: There is one java client I have wrote , which create replication slot and connection. once replication connection connects to slot I am not getting wal events. what is replication configuration do I need to set on server to work this ? https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vaibhavpatil123/eab2be72c8c7c92b097a1165278f8606/raw/8051363e981b8faf9118fd798160d266400ea42f/gistfile1.txt

Comment: "I have try even using test_decode plugin"  Please show that attempt.

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vaibhavpatil123/eab2be72c8c7c92b097a1165278f8606/raw/8051363e981b8faf9118fd798160d266400ea42f/gistfile1.txt

Comment: in case of wal2json and test decode same results as below code go to pg server and not coming back response (hangs java code)                                                                                                                
                                                                                statement.execute("select * from pg_create_logical_replication_slot('"+slotName+"', '"+wal2json+"')");

Comment: Can you see anything in the PostgreSQL log?